# Submitting multiple inputs in one form?

Tags: html, forms, input, submit

I'm currently trying to create a webpage where you can submit multiple inputs within a single form with one button. 
This is the code:

```
<form id="additem" name="item" action="add_item.php" method="get">Item Name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <br>Amount:
    <input type="text" name="amount">
    <br>
    <br>Description:
    <input size=1 00 type="text" name="desc">
    <br>
    <br>
    <select>
        <option value="picture">Picture</option>
        <option value="sculpture">Sculpture</option>
        <option value="painting">Painting</option>
        <option value="quilt">Quilt</option>
        <option value="clothing">Clothing</option>
        <option value="Pottery">Pottery</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION[ 'upload_pic'])==t rue){ echo
    "<img src =".$_SESSION[ 'upload_pic']. "><br>"; unset($_SESSION[ 'upload_pic']); }
    ?>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post">Image:
        <br>
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
</form>
```

Currently when I click the "Add" button, it does nothing, doesn't load, doesn't refresh. And I'm not sure why. If anyone has any suggestions about why that happens, that would be awesome.

Comment: You can't have nested forms in HTML. Have the image upload form outside the main form and use CSS to make it appear in the right place.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. Is there a way to accept this as an answer or should I just upvote and leave it?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use nested forms. Instead use the attribute enctype as follow:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

for `file type` you need to set the `content-type` to `multipart/alternative` only then can you upload. Also I do not see any name assigned to `select`

Answer (score 0):

Form in Form is not acceptable, you can do that, you can't nest forms like this do them side by side but not nested

Answer (score 0):

From the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form) form docs:

> Note: It's strictly forbidden to nest a form inside another form. 
>       Doing so can behave in an unpredictable way that will depend on which browser 
>       the user is using.

So remove the nested form and add the eventual php code from `upload_file.php` into `add_item.php`.